# How to shortcut this formula for calculating interest

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to calculate equal payments for loans charging daily rates with different periods.

If the periods are exactly the same i.e. 30 days, I can use a formula to work out the repayment amounts without a problem. However, I've not yet found the perfect solution to my problem.

In order to understand what I need to do I've created a spreasheet that shows the steps I'm currently taking.

- Step 1 - is to compound the interest and work out a final balance as if no repayments were made. Although the rate here is equal, this allows me to vary the rate if necessary to immitate different interest periods.
- Step 2 - calculates the running balance using the max repayment from step 1, resulting in an overpayment.
- Step 3 - I take the overpayment, divide it by the number of perds and then adjust the previous repayment. I loop through over/underpayments until the result is 0 (or near).

[image]

Whilst this currently uses a spreadsheet - the final code would be used in a program. However I can't help but think there are shortcuts to be made using tried and tested formulas.

Any advice appreciated.

P.s. I'm not a maths wizard!

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about what you're trying to achieve. Do you want a program that can take a daily rate or an APR and then work out equal monthly (not 30 day) repayments? (Which would have to consider the ongoing reduction in the principal.) This is what a bank's program would do.

Comment: Yes I'm going to use the daily rate, not APR, and calculate a repayment amount and total repayment. I understand thats what bank programs do, but this is about comparing different loans.

Comment: This is different from any question I've seen here before - it's a job! Although, not a major job; questions here and even on stackoverflow are such that people answer them for a bit of fun. 30 sterling for a python function doing that in two days via paypal?

Comment: Thanks for the offer, however I'm not a python user. I can code the above as per my example but its probably not the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Okay, hope it goes well. Anyway, I think translating from python to another language must be quite a common skill.

Answer (score 0):

With a fixed period rate, and a fixed number of periods, you can obtain a closed form. Once either of those start varying, you'd be better off going, or *required* to go, to the world of numerical methods. This would provide you with just as good answers, but will be a little more work to write. Not much more though, and you might find resources to help you over on [Personal Finance and Money](http://money.stackexchange.com).

For your specific example:

Starting with a balance $b$ and a payment $p$, you want to perform the operation $\{$ grow by 24%, then subtract $p$ $\}$ $3$ times, and end up with a result of $0$.

Let $b_n$ be the balance after $n$ repeats of the operation, so $b_0$ = $b$. Then

$$\begin{align}
b_1 & = 1.24b_0 - p \\
b_2 & = 1.24b_1 - p \\
& = 1.24(1.24b_0 - p) - p \\
& = 1.5376 b_0 - 2.24 p \\
b_3 & = 1.24b_2 - p \\
& = 1.24(1.5376 b_0 - 2.24 p) - p \\
& = 1.906624 b_0 - 3.7776 p
\end{align}$$

If we want $b_3$ to be $0$, we need to set $p$ to $1.906624 b_0 / 3.7776$, which here gives $50.47183396865735$, which in my reconstruction of your spreadsheet correctly gives a result of $0$ (allowing for floating-point inaccuracy).